# How can I check if freed a memory correctly of struct in C?

Tags: c, memory, free

Basically I'm progressing with my C basics and I have a project with operations on bidirectional list. I have finished doing all the operations I wanted like adding, viewing, reversing etc. etc. and I want to now free the list, I'm unsure how can I check if actually succeeded correctly.

```
struct element
{
    int k;
    struct element*prev;
    struct element*next;
};
```

This is how the list looks like the operations are done by switch case in a while loop and when user chooses to quit it's supposed to free the memory before breaking the while loop. There's zero problems with the whole project and it's working as intended.

```
struct element* free_list(struct element*head)
{
    struct element*temp;
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }  
}
```

And this is how I free it.

Comment: You cannot "check" whether you "actually succeeded correctly." However, your algorithm to free it is correct. So you "actually succeeded correctly."

Comment: There's no return value from free() - however, if you were trying to free an invalid pointer, your program would likely crash (on Linux, for example, you'd get an abort with ```free(): invalid pointer```) so you'd know you've done it incorrectly.

Comment: You would typically test this with software like `valgrind`.

Comment: `free_list` should be `void free_list(struct element*head)`. Just sayin'.